Cookie is not returned by Chrome back to the server
Here is how I am setting the cookie for main domain and hitting the sub domain url from Chrome in a new tab.
let cookieDomains = "xyz.com"
reply.setCookie('xyz-ses-id', accessToken, {
    path: '/',
    domain: cookieDomains,
    expires: accessTokenExpiryDate,
    secure: true,
    SameSite: "None",
    httpOnly: true
});

This is the response header for cookie that I can see in the browser
Set-Cookie:
xyz-ses-id=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhYyIsInVzZXJfaWQiOiI2NmRlYjUzOWM0NGMzNDZkMzE5OGQ5NTEiLCJvcmdfaWQiOiJBQkxDUkQtMjYyNDIwMDYiLCJpYXQiOjE3MzMxMzU5NTYsImV4cCI6MTczMzIyMjM1Nn0.JGh0xOowifJhRU7ATKaZHrCz8rhqHcEahOq4d0lZ79g; Domain=xyz.com; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 03 Dec 2024 10:39:16 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure

Still I’m not receiving the cookie in the backend for url - https://abc.xyz.com/ What am I missing here?
